# Run JavaScript after page loads

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, sitepages, classic-experience, page-load

I want to run some JavaScript (not jQuery) after the page loads in SharePoint.

What method should I include in my script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many things happen on page after `$(document).ready()`. SharePoint 2013 does provide a few options to execute JavaScript function after page loads.

1. Script on Demand (load a `.js` file then execute you code):

   ```
   function stuffThatRequiresSP_JS(){
       //your code
   }
   SP.SOD.executeFunc("sp.js", stuffThatRequiresSP_JS) ;
   ```
2. Delay until loaded (wait for a `.js` file to load, then run):

   ```
   function stuffToRunAfterSP_JS(){
       //your code
   }
   ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(stuffToRunAfterSP_JS, "sp.js");
   ```
3. Run function after other stuff finishes loading:

   ```
   function runAfterEverythingElse(){
       // your code
   }
    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("runAfterEverythingElse");
   ```

**Sources**:

1. `executeFunc`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff409592(v=office.14).aspx
2. `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff411788(v=office.14).aspx
3. For `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames`: [source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/15790.sharepoint-2010-all-about-sharepoint-javascript-function-spbodyonloadfunctionnames.aspx)

Comment: The function  $(document).ready(). is jQuery.. isn't it?  What is the javascript equivalent?

Comment: Yes, the other 3 options given in answer are using javascrip and not jquery.

Comment: Yes.. just waiting 3 minutes so they will let me :-)

Comment: One last question Ganesh... What is the javascript equivalent of this jQuery function?    var refiner = $getClientControl(document.getElementById("MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4"));

Comment: Where are you using this `$getClientControl` function? And for what?

Comment: I'm working with SharePoint Search... I want to add a refiner value (like FileType = html) so I need to access the Refiner Object. first, then use  refiner.addRefinementFilter('FileType', 'html')

Comment: @MartinMuldoon `$getClientControl` is not a jquery function. It is a sharepoint function which comes with `search.clientcontrols.js` file from layouts folder.