# SharePoint 2016 webAbsoluteUrl error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, 2016, error

When trying to implement the following code in SharePoint 2016, I get the following error:

> Unable to get property 'webAbsoluteUrl' of undefined or null reference.

The developer tool points to this line `var absoluteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;`

```
        function getData(lName){
        var absoluteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
        if(lName == "Navigation"){
        console.log(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
            var endPointUrl = absoluteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('"+lName+"')/items";
        }else{
        console.log(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
            var endPointUrl = absoluteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('"+lName+"')/items?$select=parentNav/URL, parentNav/URLNAME,subLink&$expand=parentNav";
            //console.log(endPointUrl);
        }
```

Comment: Are you using any kind of framework, or is that just bare, vanilla javascript?

Comment: Just vanilla js

Comment: Check my answer given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251853/run-javascript-after-page-loads/251854#251854), try running your code inside any of the block given in answer and let me know if it works for you or not.

Comment: Apologies for the late response.  I did see your other answer.  I tried them and got errors about undefined.  Please see pen of my code   https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/mdyPZdy?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

Try to call _spPageContextInfo in ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded like this:

```
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Ready, "sp.js");
    function Ready()
    {
       var lNmae="Navigation";
       getData(lName);

    }
    function getData(lName){
        var absoluteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
        if(lName == "Navigation"){
        console.log(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
            var endPointUrl = absoluteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('"+lName+"')/items";
        }else{
        console.log(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl);
            var endPointUrl = absoluteURL + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('"+lName+"')/items?$select=parentNav/URL, parentNav/URLNAME,subLink&$expand=parentNav";
            //console.log(endPointUrl);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Apologies for the late response.  Please see my full code which uses jquery document.ready().  https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/mdyPZdy?editors=0010    Not sure how to implement it here.