# Jquery not loading on inital page load for suitebar links

Tags: javascript, jquery, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, suitebar

I am trying to edit the SharePoint 2016 suitebar links and want to replace "sites" with a custom name and link. I have been able to edit the name via CSS but need to edit the link using JavaScript as I don't believe there is another way. When I launch the page, my function is always hit but the link doesn't always change. It takes a refresh before the Jquery works successfully.

I have tried using document.ready and I've tried delaying by using a timeout but those have not worked.

Here is my simple code:

```
$(window).load(function nav() {
   var $link = $(".o365cs-nav-appTitle");
   $link.attr('href', 'site URL');
});
```

Comment: Try using work arounds given in my answer at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251853/run-javascript-after-page-loads/251854#251854

Answer (score 2):

A solution that works for sure, but which I don't like, is to hijack the render function of the suite bar. See below.

Ideally, there should be a callback function provided by SharePoint that allows us to run JS code after the suite bar has finished rendering, but there is none of that AFAIK.

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('suitenav.js', '_o365sg2c.O365Shell._renderInternal$p', function () {
  var oldRenderInternal = _o365sg2c.O365Shell._renderInternal$p;

  window._o365sg2c.O365Shell._renderInternal$p = function (c, b, a) {
    oldRenderInternal(c, b, a);

    var brandBar = document.getElementById('Sites_BrandBar');
    if (brandBar) {
      brandBar.setAttribute('href', 'site URL');
    }
  }
});
```