# jQuery hiding column based on another column's value

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, javascript, jquery, list-form

I've successfully used the following script in `NewForm.aspx` to hide a column 'Date SharePoint checked' when another column 'Check SharePoint?' is set to 'No'.

When I open the same list item in `EditForm.aspx` or `ListForm.aspx` I need it to also hide the column. The script works when the Yes/No column is changed, but I need it to work on the existing value when the item is opened. Can the existing script be modified for that? Thanks.

```
//Show/hide columns based on Drop Down Selection
$(&quot;select[title=&#39;Check SharePoint?&#39;]&quot;).change(function() {
if ($(&quot;select[title=&#39;Check SharePoint?&#39;]&quot;).val() != &quot;Yes&quot;)
{
$(&#39;nobr:contains(&quot;Date SharePoint Checked&quot;)&#39;).closest(&#39;tr&#39;).hide();
}
else
{
$(&#39;nobr:contains(&quot;Date SharePoint Checked&quot;)&#39;).closest(&#39;tr&#39;).show();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below code on your `EditForm.aspx` page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("select[title='Check SharePoint?']").val() != "Yes") {
        $('nobr:contains("Date SharePoint Checked")').closest('tr').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('nobr:contains("Date SharePoint Checked")').closest('tr').show();
    }
});
```

**OR***:

```
function runAfterPageLoads(){
    if ($("select[title='Check SharePoint?']").val() != "Yes") {
        $('nobr:contains("Date SharePoint Checked")').closest('tr').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('nobr:contains("Date SharePoint Checked")').closest('tr').show();
    }
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("runAfterPageLoads");
```

If this doesn't work then try one of the solutions given in my answer in below link:

[Run Javascript after page loads](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251853/run-javascript-after-page-loads/251854#251854)

Answer (score 0):

Use $(document).ready function to check the column value and hide another column, here is the final modified code snippet for your reference:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("select[title='Check SharePoint?']").val() != "Yes") {
        $('nobr:contains("Date SharePoint Checked")').closest('tr').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('nobr:contains("Date SharePoint Checked")').closest('tr').show();
    }
    
    
        $("select[title='Check SharePoint?']").change(function() {
            if ($("select[title='Check SharePoint?']").val() != 'Yes')
            {
            $("nobr:contains('Date SharePoint Checked')").closest("tr").hide();
            }
            else
            {
            $("nobr:contains('Date SharePoint Checked')").closest("tr").show();
            }
        });

});
</script>
```