# Adding space between radio buttons

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, javascript, list-form

is there any way we can add space between the choice fields (Radio Buttons)?

For instance if I want to make space between Youth and Adult what would be the steps?

[image]

Comment: Is this **classic experience** list form? You want to do this for particular radio field or all radio fields on page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://cdn.bootcdn.net/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  $('[title="Youth"]').closest("tr").css("display","block").css("margin-top","-15px")
  $('[title="Adult"]').closest("tr").css("display","block").css("margin-top","15px")
  
})
</script>
```

Test result:

[image]

Comment: Hey Amos, you are great man. Thanks for your help

Comment: If my reply helps you, you could accept it as the answer. Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

To add spacing between all radio buttons of all choice fields, use below reusable function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function addSpaceBetweenRadio(){
        var tableCollection = document.querySelectorAll("table[id$='_ChoiceRadioTable']");

        for(var i = 0; i < tableCollection.length; i++) {
            var tBody = tableCollection[i].children;
            var trCollection = tBody[0].children;
            
            for(var index = 0; index < trCollection.length; index++) {
                trCollection[index].style.display = "block";
                trCollection[index].style.marginBottom = "10px";
            }
        }
    }

    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("addSpaceBetweenRadio");

</script>
```

Use below steps to add this code on list form page:

1. Go to your list form. (Example new form URL: `<siteUrl>/Lists/<listName>/NewForm.aspx`)
2. Edit page
3. Add Script Editor/Content Editor web part
4. Add above code in web part
5. Save/Publish list form page

**Sample Output**: Showing spacing between all radio buttons of all choice fields

[image]

**Related links**: [Run JavaScript after page loads](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251853/run-javascript-after-page-loads/251854#251854)

---

No need to add reference to any external library like `jQuery`. Above code uses plain JavaScript.