# I'm trying to run a javascript script through the script editor in sharepoint online, but nothing happens

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, web-part, jquery, script-editor-webpart

In the script editor I have this code to disable some buttons:

```
<script>
document.getElementById(id="Status_c15b34c3-ce7d-490a-b133-3f4de8801b76_$DropDownChoice_Aprovado").disabled = true;
document.getElementById(id ="Status_c15b34c3-ce7d-490a-b133-3f4de8801b76_$DropDownChoice_Rejeitada").disabled = true;
document.getElementById(id="ctl00_ctl32_g_b2a57244_e74a_4dc6_90d1_809ce3ff419a_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl00_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem").disabled = true;
document.getElementById(id="ctl00_ctl32_g_b2a57244_e74a_4dc6_90d1_809ce3ff419a_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl01_ctl00_diidIOGoBack").disabled = true;
</script>
```

However, in the browser console, I can get the expected result, but when I run it inside the script editor, nothing happens.

Comment: Are you using classic experience pages in SharePoint online?

Comment: I'm using the classic experience. Thank you, this solution worked!

Comment: Try code given in my answer below & let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code in script editor web part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function runAfterEverythingElse(){
        // your code
        document.getElementById(id="Status_c15b34c3-ce7d-490a-b133-3f4de8801b76_$DropDownChoice_Aprovado").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById(id ="Status_c15b34c3-ce7d-490a-b133-3f4de8801b76_$DropDownChoice_Rejeitada").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById(id="ctl00_ctl32_g_b2a57244_e74a_4dc6_90d1_809ce3ff419a_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl00_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem").disabled = true;
        document.getElementById(id="ctl00_ctl32_g_b2a57244_e74a_4dc6_90d1_809ce3ff419a_ctl00_toolBarTbl_RightRptControls_ctl01_ctl00_diidIOGoBack").disabled = true;
    }

    _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("runAfterEverythingElse");

</script>
```

Make sure you are using correct selectors for your buttons.

**Reference**: [Run Javascript after page loads](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251853/run-javascript-after-page-loads/251854#251854)