# Execute JavaScript when SharePoint do a partial page load

Tags: sharepoint-server, modern-experience, 2019

We've added a custom JavaScript to SharePoint 2019 on all modern pages (it's just a standard script tag, `<script src="..." type="module">`). It works fine except when SharePoint do a partial page load, then the script won't execute. I don't understand why or when SharePoint decide to do a full- or a partial page load, some links do, some don't. But it happens when I go from one library to another using the left navigation links (Quickstart).

Is it possible to execute my script even when the page is not fully loaded? I've experimented a bit using observers, because the  changes when I go to another page obviously, and so I thought i could hooked up on that one. But with no luck.

Comment: You can try these 2 things: (1) Check this solution for properly loading your custom JS on site page: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251853/run-javascript-after-page-loads/251854#251854. (2) Try deactivating [Minimal Download Strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/general-development/minimal-download-strategy-overview?wt.mc_id=MVP_315224) feature from site settings. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP Thanks, but I’ve already tried that. The script has already fired, and the partial load won’t trigger it again. MDS makes no difference whether it’s activated or not.