SP2019: jQuery to Disable Mult Lines of Text Field_Plain Text
I have tried almost every permutation of jQuery to disable a multi line text field (plain text) named [Client]. Same internal name as display name.  The 4 lines below have been tried one a time with no success. I need help. Been doing this for a long time and starting to wonder if SP2019 is different from SP2013. I welcome guidance
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

$("textarea[title='Client']").prop('disabled', true);
$("textarea[title='Client']").prop('disabled', 'disabled');
$("textarea[title='Client']").attr('disabled', true);
$("textarea[title='Client']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

});
</script>


I've also reviewed and tried many solutions posted here, but I'm not having success.

Have you tried debugging? Is the selector finding the field? Your code might run before the page has finished loading and you need to make sure that the code run after the site has loaded. Read more here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251853/run-javascript-after-page-loads

Try this code:
$("div[id^='Client']").attr("contentEditable","false").css('background-color','#F6F6F6');

